# Stress relaxation time scale

Tags: fluid-dynamics, material-science, polymers

What is the definition and physical meaning of "stress relaxation time scale" in (non-Newtonian) fluids?

Comment: I suggest you go look this up first. There are plenty of sources explaining principles of rheology and viscous materials

Comment: @jaywalker I did my best (I'm new to the field of rheology). I understand the concept of the stress relaxation but I am asking about the specific definition of the "relaxation time scale". Can you provide a good reference which describe this specific term?

Comment: Time-scale is generally pretty vague and depends on the application and how someone chooses to define it.  There is no strict definition, so context is very important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In essence the stress relaxation time, is the time that a viscoelastic substance requires to reach steady state on a molecular level after being deformed under some stress. You could also refer to it as the "bounce-back" time of the substance.

A number of different mechanisms may be involved in how a material behaves after stress has been applied to it and is then removed. Some of these are outlined in this source:
http://polymerdatabase.com/polymer%20physics/Relaxation.html

Another useful source as an introduction to the topic is:
https://www.whoi.edu/fileserver.do?id=28331&pt=10&p=17274